# Extending re.partner, in OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo

I'm currently using Open ERP. I'd like to extend the Customers/Organistion form with some added fields.

I'm under the impression that the Customers Object model is res.partner.

Here is my code so far:

```
from osv import fields, osv

class starstream_customers(osv.osv):
    _name = 'starstream.customers'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    _table = 'res_partner'
    _columns = {
        'caller_id': fields.char('Caller ID',size=128),
        'rating': fields.selection([
            ('none', '--None--'),
            ('shutdown', 'Shutdown'),
            ('aquired', 'Aquired'),
            ('active', 'Active'),
            ('cancelled', 'Project Cancelled')
            ], 'Rating'),
        'industry': fields.char('Industry',size=265),
        'type':fields.selection([
            ('supplier', 'Supplier'),
            ('customer', 'Customer'),
            ('old_customer', 'Old Customer'),
            ('supplier', 'Supplier'),
            ('customer_support_team', 'Customers Support Team'),
            ('none', '--None--'),
            ], 'Type'),
        'invoice_address': fields.char('Invoice Address',size=512),
        'employees': fields.integer('Employees'),
    }
starstream_customers()
```

And my view file:

```
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_starstream_customers">
            <field name="name">starstream.customers.tree</field>
            <field name="model">starstream.customers</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <field name="name" position="after">
                    <field name="rating"/>
                </page>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

For now, i'm only trying to add in the rating field, just till its working.

Every time I try to re-write this I get:

```
TypeError: The model "('res.partner',)" specifies an unexisting parent class "('res.partner',)"
You may need to add a dependency on the parent class' module.
```

I cannot see where i'm going wrong, can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few problems here:

You have defined both a `_name` and a `_inherit` and they have different values. There is nothing wrong this if what you want is a whole new table called `starstream.customers` whose columns are a superset of the `res.partner` model with your new ones added in but then you are using the existing res_partner table for storage.

If however, you just want to add your columns into the existing res.parter model so a partner has all their existing information plus your new columns then the usual pattern is to just have the _inherit and take out the _name and the _table.  You will find a couple of places with this pattern, stock.picking.in and stock.picking.out for example, but unless you are sure of what you are doing I wouldn't recommend it.

If you want the later, which is the pattern for 95% of table extensions, remove the _name and _table attributes and just leave the inherit.

This is optional but if you are coding for OpenERP version 7 you should inherit `osv.Model`, not `osv.osv`.  `osv.osv` works but is deprecated.  Also for release 7, you do not need to instantiate your model.

In your form definition, you are using model `starstream.customers` but trying to inherit a form for a different model (`res.partners`) which is what is triggering the actual error you are seeing.  As you are using a different model, you will need to do a full form.  If  you go with the suggestion above and remove the `_name` and `_table` from your model then you can change the model on your form to `res.partner` and it should just work.

Not sure why you need to add a dependency on crm for the code above, res.partner is in the base module.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. Inherting osv.Model worked, and i'll check the view xml shortly.

Comment: "This is optional but if you are coding for OpenERP version 7 you should inherit osv.Model, not osv.osv. osv.osv works but is deprecated. Also for release 7, you do not need to instantiate your model." - is there a place where I can find these "developer changes"? I've come across a lot of these little (good - osv.Model is undoubtedly better than osv.osv) changes, and they are basically undocumented

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have `crm` added to your dependencies.

**__openerp__.py**

```
'depends': ['base', 'crm'],
```